# Let $k^* = (e \ln n) / \ln \ln n$ . Show $\left(\frac{e}{k^*}\right)^{k^*}\frac{1}{1-e/k^*} \leq 1/n^2$

Tags: probability, inequality

I'm reading a math book. They considered the problem of randomly placing m balls into n containers. In attempt to prove that with a high probability no container contains a certain amount of balls they make the following claim

Let

If $k^* = \lceil(e \ln n) / \ln \ln n\rceil$ . Then $$\left(\frac{e}{k^*}\right)^{k^*}\frac{1}{1-e/k^*} \leq 1/n^2.$$

But they give no explanation of the claim and I can't prove it myself. Can someone help me?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor, thanks for finding the other question. I was about to type in an answer.

Comment: Please check $n = 200$ (I got $k = 9$, LHS > RHS).